# How to find particular position object from array in swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview

I inserted some objects in my below finalArray array. Now I want to display them in tableList so that each position object I need to find. How can I write that statement can some one help me please?

### My code:-

```
 var forcast:Forecast?
 var finalArray = [Forecast]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
     forcast = finalArray.index(indexpath);
    }
```

Comment: `finalArray[indexpath.row]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var finalArray = [Forecast]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
    let forcast = finalArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

[CollectionTypes documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html)

```
var row: Int
```

The value of the row element of the index path.

```
var section: Int
```

The value of the section element of the index path.

[IndexPath documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/indexpath)

Answer (score 0):

[NSIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsindexpath/1614934-init) has section and row

You need to access based on the `indexPath.section` or `indexPath.row` based on how you are categorising your data on tableView with the use [tableView datasource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource)

Ex:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
     forcast = finalArray.index(indexpath.row);//
}
```